# Parametrization of a torus - Surjectivity

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $T^2=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:(x^2+y^2+z^2+3)^2=16(x^2+y^2)\}$.
I want to prove that $h(u,\phi)=((2+\cos u)\cos \phi,(2+\cos u)\sin \phi,\sin u)$ defines local parameterizations for $T^2$.

First of all, it seems to me that the word "parametrization" is defined in different ways. I think the appropriate definition here is: a bijective smooth map from "a set of coordinates" to our set $T^2$. Notice that it does not need to be a chart.

Smoothness is clear.
I already proved that all points of the form $(x,y,z)=h(u,\phi)$ are in $T^2$ (*i.e.* Im$h\subseteq T^2$). I am having trouble proving that $T^2\subseteq \text{Im}h$, thus establishing surjectivity. I believe this amounts to showing that the system of equations

$$
\begin{cases}  (x^2+y^2+z^2+3)^2=16(x^2+y^2)
\\              x = (2+\cos u)\cos \phi
\\              y = (2+\cos u)\sin \phi
\\              z = \sin u
\end{cases}
$$
has a solution $(u,\phi)$. However, do not know how to do it.

To prove injectivity, I also have to solve a system of equations, but I do not think this will be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're right. There's no abstract solution here. The hint I would offer is to manipulate the cartesian equation a bit algebraically (start by setting $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and then do something obvious).

Answer (score 0):

Pick a point $x \in U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, which is your $(u, \phi)-$euclidean space. Check for conditions of the inverse function theorem for the map $h: U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{T}^2$

(In this context, co-ordinates are maps from patches of the manifold to the euclidean space, and parametrization is its inverse)

Comment: How does that prove surjectivity?

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm now confused. This is the torus being parametrized as a surface of revolution and $h_{\ast}(\frac{\partial}{\partial u})$ etc are independent.

Comment: Maybe the algebraic set given by the equation has a whole other component separate from the torus? How would you ever find that out? You can certainly make up examples of such a phenomenon.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh I see. Btw, love your book!

Comment: LOL, thanks so much, @sntx. Interestingly, this is an exercise somewhere in there, if we're thinking about the same book.